# Ruby on rails3: Link_to not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
 <%= link_to "", { :controller => 'board', 
                            :action => 'take_turn', 
                            :id => @board.id,
                            :x => col, 
                            :y => row }, :remote => true do %>
```

generates:

```
<a href="" action="take_turn" controller="board" id="15" x="0" y="1">
            <div class="ttt_square"> 
              &nbsp;
            </div>
</a>
```

Why is it not working right? It should generate `herf="board/take_turn?id=15&x=1&y=1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add parenthesis to get it right with your notation, just like this:

```
<%= link_to({:controller => 'board', 
                        :action => 'take_turn', 
                        :id => @board.id,
                        :x => col, 
                        :y => row }, :remote => true) do %> 
    <div class="ttt_square"> 
          &nbsp;
    </div>
<% end %>
```

otherwise the interpreter can't understand which are the correct arguments. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're using the block version of `link_to`. The first parameter in this case should be the URL, not a blank string.

Comment: I get syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '} when I get rid of the empty string. =\

Comment: Wrap the arguments of the `link_to` in parenthesis too.

Comment: To elaborate, if you have `link_to {...} do ...`, Ruby can't figure out if you are using hash syntax or block syntax (and assumes it's a block). `link_to({...}) do ...` helps it figure out that you are meaning to pass a hash.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to board_take_turn_path(@board, :x => col, :y => row) , :remote => true do %>
# Your code and stuff here
<% end %>
```

I think should work (You need to make sure that `board_take_turn_path` is actually defined

Comment: I need it to be the block version of link_to because I have a div that is an entire link

Comment: webdestroya is giving you the block version. Just put whatever you want to go in the block after his code, append an `<% end %>`, and you'll be good to go!